# PowerBi Join column value strings together in each row

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like shown below titled Employees:

```
Name     LOC1     LOC2     LOC3     LOC4
-----------------------------------------
Joe      DAY      CVG      DTW
Jane     PVD      STL  
John     LAX      SAN      SFO      ANC
```

I created a measure to combine the LOC fields into 1 result separated by a space.  I keep getting errors because PBi wants to aggregate the data fields.  All fields are type Text.  I've tried all the usual combine methods, below are a couple of examples...

```
CombineLOCs=CONCATENATE('Employees'[LOC1],'Employees'[LOC2])

CombineLOCs= 'Employees'[LOC1] & " " & 'Employees"[LOC2]
```

This is what I get back:
[image]

"A single value for column 'LOC1' in table 'Employees' cannot be determined.  This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation....etc."

I ultimately have a table visual on my canvas and instead of listing out all of the columns on that table, I just want 1 column with all of the combined LOC values for each employee in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a single column where the LOC columns are joined together, then you need to create a new column within the table, rather than a new measure. A measure expects you to aggregate the values. A column will concatenate the text strings on a row by row basis.

If you select the new column option, either on the table tools or the fields sidebar, then use the concatenate formula in your question, that should work.

With the new column, you can then include the employee name and the associated LOC values.

Comment: excellent, thanks for the clarification!!  So it would be a calculated column?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, here is [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-columns) from the power bi docs. You could also do this in Power Query, [example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-common-query-tasks)